# Sed pattern is not substituting into desired result

Tags: regex, linux, sed

I am trying hackers rank problem for sed. I tried to write my own solution but it did not worked. I am unable to figure out why my solution is not working

Sample Problem: A file containing credit card number say "4321 5667 8765 1234". I have to change this pattern to "**** **** **** 1234"

Sed pattern I have written is

```
sed 's/([0-9]{4}) ([0-9]{4}) ([0-9]{4}) ([0-9]{4})/**** **** **** \4/' sample_data
```

It is giving output as

```
4321 5667 8765 1234
```

`It seems like sed is not matching pattern and that is the reason it is printing string as it is`

I know some smaller solutions like

```
sed 's/[^ ]* /****/g'
```

This is working

I again tried

```
sed 's/[^ ]+ /****/g' # replaced with * with +
```

It is not matching any pattern.

Comment: `()` and `{}` have to be escaped in sed (basic regular expressions), or you have to use `sed -E` (or `sed -r`) to enable extended regular expressions. Also, you don't need to capture the first three groups.

Comment: Thanks. Do you know about this `sed 's/[^ ]+ /****/g'`

Comment: What do you mean, "do you know about this"? It doesn't work because `+` is also extended and has to be escaped in BRE.

Comment: Yes thanks a lot for the info. Can I use -E everytime in sed so I do not have to care for extended patterns

Comment: Instead of matching not a space, you could also match 4 digits `sed 's/[0-9]\{4\} /**** /g' ./sample_data`

Comment: You can't not care; using `sed` vs. `sed -E` implies exactly what has to be escaped and what doesn't have to be, see [the manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#BRE-vs-ERE).

Answer (score 1):

A slightly shorter option using global replacement can be written as:

```
sed -E 's/[0-9]{4}\s+/**** /g'
```

Which uses the *extended regex* to match:

- `[0-9]{4}\s+` digits `{four of them}` and at least one *whitespace*; and
- replace them with `"**** "`

An equivalent (but longer) *basic regex* would be:

```
sed 's/[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]\s\s*/**** /g'
```

Where each of the digits is listed expressly and `\s\s*` matches one or more whitespace with the same replacement applied. BRE doesn't support the `{4}` pattern repetition or `+` that ERE does.

Also, since hackerrank is heavy on tripping you up with *corner-cases*, you may want to trim leading and trailing whitespace before you process the numbers, e.g.

```
sed -e 's/^\s*//' -e 's/\s*$//' -e 's/[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]\s\s*/**** /g'
```

That way you can also handle lines like:

```
"  4321 5667 8765 1234  "
```

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple issues with your `sed` command:

1. Not escaping `()` and `{}` while using `sed` or else use `-E` or `-r` for extended regular expressions, as given in `man sed`:

   `-E, -r, --regexp-extended`

   `use extended regular expressions in the script.`
2. Missing the printing of the pattern space.

   `p`

   `Print the current pattern space.`

Also, there's no need to capture the first 3 number groups.

`sed` command:

`sed -r -n 's/^[0-9]{4}\s+[0-9]{4}\s+[0-9]{4}\s+([0-9]{4})/**** **** **** \1/p' sample_data`

`\s` :

`Matches whitespace characters (spaces and tabs).`